# IOS handoff without iCloud

Tags: ios, handoff

For one of our app requirements, we have implemented handoff feature in an iOS app which uses iCloud.This part works well.
But for a use-case we are exploring possibilities of having handoff with an enterprise Cloud. Is it possible or will it be like reinventing the wheel to use our own server for backing up data and taking care of syncing data with the devices associated with a particular login id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be like reinventing the wheel. As a bonus you will probably not be able to identify the specific device if a user is logged in on multiple devices as Apple has deprecated the UDID.

Comment: What if I still want to implement it. How can we identify the devices which are to be synced without the iCloud? Instead of udid I could use MAC address.